# MongoDB changes String

Tags: mongodb

I have a new collection, with auto-id activated, and when I do the following:

```
db.collection.insert({"ip":"144.29.10.94"});
```

Then in the db the record is the following:

```
  {
  "ip": "3134342e32392e31302e3934",
  "_id": "572b730d77c05fdc2516d8d2"
  }
```

It might be ridiculous but I don't know why the IP address, which is a string, is converted this way? How to avoid this?

Thanks a lot,

Regards

```
D:\repo_git>mongod --version
db version v3.2.5
git version: 34e65e5383f7ea1726332cb175b73077ec4a1b02
allocator: tcmalloc
modules: none
build environment:
    distarch: x86_64
    target_arch: x86_64
```

Comment: Cannot replicate at all.

Comment: I don't know why this is happening but I can say that it is converted to hexadecimal.

Comment: Another interesting thing is that it does not happen on all ip addresses. for example this one : 
`{"ip":"172.29.11.154"}` works

Comment: Works fine here. Are you doing this in the shell?

Comment: Yes.. I did it in the shell and using MongoClient.com as well.
I see that nobody reproduces it so it might be something very particular...

Comment: Are you able to consistently reproduce this in the `mongo` shell by inserting the same data? If so, can you try starting the shell with `mongo --norc` and see if the issue is still reproducible? What is the output of `version()` in the shell?

Comment: I can reproduce this bug in MongoClient 1.0.1 and have reported on GitHub: https://github.com/rsercano/mongoclient/issues/73. I would suggest using the standard `mongo` shell that matches your MongoDB server version if you want to ensure full compatibility.

Comment: With the right-floating checkbox unchecked it works perfectly in MongoClient.

I am 100% sure I had the bug yesterday in the mongo shell as well, but it seems to work today.... Perhaps I am getting crazy. I tried everything, even start populating the collection with MongoClient and then coming back to it with the shell, but the IPs are properly handled.
So I guess this is solved. For more info go on the github link given by Stennie. Thanks.